# Не получается запустить локальный сервер (Python,Django)

Tags: python, django, cmd

Создаю виртуальное окружение, устанавливаю в него django, активирую его. 
После я перемещаюсь в директорию, где находиться файл manage.py, решаю, что для того, чтобы запустить сервер мне необходимо ввести: `python manage.py runserver`. Не прошло. Вот лог из командной строки:

```
(lol) R:\Новая папка (4)\lol\courses_django\courses_django>python manage.py runs
erver
C:\Users\artem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe: can't open
file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

(lol) R:\Новая папка (4)\lol\courses_django\courses_django>cd ..

(lol) R:\Новая папка (4)\lol\courses_django>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 15 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you
 apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
February 10, 2019 - 10:07:22
Django version 2.1.5, using settings 'courses_django.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper
 at 0x031F7E88>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "R:\Новая папка (4)\lol\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", li
ne 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "R:\Новая папка (4)\lol\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands
\runserver.py", line 139, in inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading, server_cls=self.server_cls)
  File "R:\Новая папка (4)\lol\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py
", line 203, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "R:\Новая папка (4)\lol\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py
", line 67, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\artem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserve
r.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\artem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\sim
ple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\artem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\server
.py", line 139, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Users\artem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py",
 line 676, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 6: invalid
continuation byte
```

Работал с установленным python 3.7.2, с django 2.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что имя вашего компьютера содержит кириллические символы. Да и в пути к проекту нежелательно иметь каталоги с русскими названиями.